# d3js Force-Directed Arrows do not appear at the end of Path

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to visualize a graph with arrows and the nodes are images. I pretty much followed [this](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5141278). However, the arrow do not appear at the end of path. Its like this:[image]

How can I overcome this? Furthermore, I want to set the links at the center of the images. Because by default they appear at the left top. I thought about adding a width value to `d.source.x` in the tick but then I get an `Error: Problem parsing d="some number"`.

```
var svg = d3.select('#graph-visualization')
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr("height", canvas.height)
    .attr("width", canvas.width)
    .attr("id", "canvas");

svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["end"])      // Different link/path types can be defined here
    .enter().append("svg:marker")    // This section adds in the arrows
    .attr("id", String)
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 10)
    .attr("markerHeight", 10)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5"); 

var nodes = [],
    links = [];

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(.05)
    .linkDistance(100)
    .charge(-1000)
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .size([$('svg').attr('height'), $('svg').attr('width')]);

var node = svg.selectAll(".node"),
    link = svg.selectAll('.link');

var drag = force.drag().on("dragstart", dragstart);

function update() {
    link = link.data(links, function(d) { 
        return d.source.id + '-' + d.target.id; 
    });

    var linktag = link.enter().append("g").attr("class", "link");
    var linkline = linktag.append("svg:path")
        .attr("class", "linkline")
        .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");

    node = node.data(force.nodes(), function(d) { 
                return d.id; 
    });
    node.exit().remove();
    var appended = node.enter().append("g").call(drag);
    appended.append('image')
        .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
             return someURLthatcontainsanImage;
        })
        .attr('x', '-8px')
        .attr('y', '-8px');
}
force.on("tick", function(e) {
     link.selectAll("path").attr("d", function(d) {
        var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
             dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
             dr = 0;
             return "M" + 
             d.source.x + 
             "," + 
             d.source.y +
             "A" + 
             dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + 
             d.target.x +
             "," + 
             d.target.y;
    });
});
```

Comment: Where do you bind the marker to the path? i.e `.attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");` and a fiddle would help a lot in answering this question.

Comment: I added the code in the question. Thanks. I will create a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting

```
.attr("refX", 15)
.attr("refY", -1.5)
```

you are setting the marker's reference point to [coordinates](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#MarkerElementRefXAttribute) `[15, -1.5]`. This point in the marker's coordinate system will be rendered at the end of the line giving the offset you are witnessing.

Given that the marker is an arrow you probably want this point to be either

- `[0, 0]` placing its base at the end of the line or

  ```
  .attr("refX", 0)   // may be omitted, defaults to 0
  .attr("refY", 0)   // may be omitted, defaults to 0
  ```
- `[10, 0]` placing its tip at the end of the line.

  ```
  .attr("refX", 10)
  .attr("refY", 0)   // may be omitted, defaults to 0
  ```

Note, that both `refX` and `refY` default to `0` in which case there is no need to set them explicitly.

Comment: Nice. That does it. Thank you so much. Do you also have a hint on how to make path start and end at the center of the image?

Comment: @riasc That seems to be question in its own right. Please post another question describing your problem.